Formatting Pulumi Automation API Stdout as JSON
I'm using the Pulumi Automation API in Go, and I want to format the standard output (stdout) as JSON. Currently, I handle stdout like this:
stdoutStreamer := optup.ProgressStreams(os.Stdout)
_, err = stack.Up(context.Background(), stdoutStreamer)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to update stack: %v\n\n", err)
}

Is there a simple and easy way to have the output formatted as JSON? Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

The first hit of this search query explains how to create "something" which can be passed to stack.Up as its second argument. You can easily adapt that example to output JSON-formatted data.

There seems to be no equivalent of pulumi up -j option in go automation API. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/auto/optup . Is there a workaround? Anyone?

Thanks @kostix . adding the exact section here that shows the code example you wanted to show - https://www.pulumi.com/blog/observability-with-infrastructure-as-code/#adding-infrastructure-observability . This does text parsing on the printed lines.
